# Jquery visible selector in combination with fading elements in and out

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am designing a scroll page that has certain effects, such as buttons appearing and dissapearing. The idea is too fade in a button as the user scrolls that section into view, and as the user leaves that area it fades out again.

i have the following jQuery script using the visible class i downloaded:

```
 // Fade out enquire button on page load.
   $( ".enquireNow" ).fadeOut();
 // Check to see if element is visible when user scrolls
   $(window).scroll(function() {
       if ($('.miniCity').visible()) {
          $( ".enquireNow" ).fadeIn();
        }
   });
```

First of all is this best practice, are there better ways to achieve this? Second, how do i make the button dissapear again when the element scrolls out of view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

Comment: https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one,

```
if($('.miniCity').visible(true)){
    $(".enquireNow").fadeIn();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `.is()` function along with `:visible` selector,

```
 if ($('.miniCity').is(':visible')) {
```

Comment: this checks css visible property or element is in the current area which is displayed?

Comment: Closing parenthesis of if is missing

Comment: hmmm it seems that your answer, is always true, even when it is not in the viewport.